# python pandas how to remove after specific string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an data frame like this

```
      details
      Pinene 0.16%, Borneol 0.08%, Myrcene 0.12%,Total terpenes content 1.00%, Parents Strains Kandy KushCookie Monster

      Pinene 0.18%, Borneol 0.08%, Myrcene 0.2%,Total terpenes content 05.00%, Parents Strains Kandy KushCookie Monster
```

I want to remove everything after Total terpenes content. so my expected data frame will be look like this:

```
          details
          Pinene 0.16%, Borneol 0.08%, Myrcene 0.12%,Total terpenes content 1.00%
    
          Pinene 0.18%, Borneol 0.08%, Myrcene 0.2%,Total terpenes content 05.00%
```

Comment: How are you creating this DataFrame? Why is it not in multiple columns, e.g. split on `,`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# using regex extract everything prior to 'Total terpenes content' and until
# positive lookahead of ","
# and assign back to details column

df['details']=df['details'].str.extract(r'(.*Total terpenes content.*(?=,))' )
df
```

```
0    Pinene 0.16%, Borneol 0.08%, Myrcene 0.12%,Tot...
1    Pinene 0.18%, Borneol 0.08%, Myrcene 0.2%,Tota...
Name: details, dtype: object
```

Comment: Naveed Thanks can you please explain this `(?=,))`?

Comment: It’s a regency ‘positivelook ahead’. It checks for the  presence of the comma without capturing it, and serves as the end of pattern.

Comment: how to remove first character ? I want to remove only first comma `,Insomnia,Heightened sensory perception,Concern,Dry eyes` .I tried this `df['effects'] = df['effects'].str.extract(r'(^,)' )` but didn't work. my expected data frame will be look like this `Insomnia,Heightened sensory perception,Concern,Dry eyes`

Comment: I think this is unrelated to this question. However, one way is to use lstrip and specify comma as a character to remove. Check this https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_lstrip.asp